# Можно ли вместо двоеточия поставить запятую или тире?

Tags: пунктуация

И на прекрасном фоне золотого солнца, голубых небес, зеленых рощ и садов – всегда на первом плане, всегда на главном месте она: непостижимая, недосягаемая, несравненная, единственная, восхитительная, головокружительная – Юлия.

**Можно ли вместо двоеточия поставить запятую или тире, объяснив это тем, что "непостижимая, недосягаемая, несравненная, единственная, восхитительная, головокружительная – Юлия." - приложение ?**

Есть ли другие варианты?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запятую на месте двоеточия можно поставить. 
**§ 61. Распространенные приложения, стоящие после определяемого слова — существительного или местоимения, а также отделенные от них другими членами предложения или относящиеся к отсутствующему члену предложения, обособляются запятыми**: ... *Вон она, хищница подводного мира, плещется на вешнем льду (Аст.); Они, мать и обе дочери, были дома (Ч.); Они очень разные, эти строки, они противостоят друг другу (Зал.); Он думал всю эту ночь, Вершинин-старший (Зал.); Он был горек и духовит, этот крылатый, степной, восточный ветер (Шол.)* (http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=161#pg161)
**Тире перед словом "Юлия"** оправдано. Это интонационное тире, выделяющее имя, которое должно быть произнесено с особой эмоциональной силой. 
  Слово "Юлия" вместе со всеми зависимыми от него прилагательными действительно приложение, которое от определяемого слова ОНА может быть отделено **запятой**. 
**Тире** тоже могло бы быть, если бы не было двух других тире - интонационных. Тире ставится, если приложение достаточно распространено, если стоит в конце предложения. Такое приложение обладает большей самостоятельностью. Но у нас слишком много тире получается...
Авторскую **точку с запятой** нужно понять и принять: пауза значительная, знаков в первой части предложения много, во второй тоже.
***И на прекрасном фоне золотого солнца, голубых небес, зеленых рощ и садов – всегда на первом плане, всегда на главном месте она; непостижимая, недосягаемая, несравненная, единственная, восхитительная, головокружительная – Юлия.***

Comment: Так на авторскую-то никто и не покушался вроде...

>Запятую на месте двоеточия можно поставить 
     
Cмысл изменится. Незначительно, но всё-таки. Хотя и двоеточие тоже меняет его по сравнению с авторским.

Answer (score 0):

Хмм... Будем пока считать, что я "Юнкеров" не читал и выбираю из двух зол.
Если не ошибаюсь, это тот самый случай, который пытались оговорить в так и не принятом проекте "реформы" (на самом деле - уточнения) орфографии, разрешив заменять двоеточие на тире почти везде. Проект не приняли, а приложения я тут не вижу. Хотя признаю, у меня взгляд на эти вещи несколько специфический, я сам склонен против всяких правил ставить тире вместо двоеточий.
Но в данном случае не вижу причин. Двоеточие тут смотрелось бы естественнее.

ЗЫ Оставьте как у автора. Там точка с запятой.)))

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что здесь классический пример, предложенный Розенталем: приложение, носящее пояснительный характер и стоящее в конце предожения,выделяется тире, т.е. в данном предложении знаки должны стоять так: "...она - непостижимая, недосягаемая, несравненная, единственная, восхитительная, головокружительная Юлия".